# Div fading on focus of text area

Tags: javascript, jquery, focus, fadein

I have a div that needs to fade out on focus of the text area within my form.

I have the following JS file to perform this, *"message"* is the class of my text area and *"bubble"* is the ID of the div that should fade in/out. I've also included it directly into my page to see if that fixed it.

```
function (){

$(".message").focus(function() {
$("#bubble").fadeOut();
   }).blur(function() {
    $("#bubble").fadeIn();
   });
})();
```

The HTML is as follows, not that it's particularly interesting!

```
 <div id="bubble">
    <img src="images/hire_me_bubble.png" alt="Hire me" />
 </div>
```

The live site can be seen [here](http://www.jamesperrett.co.uk/testsite/) - the text area in the contact form should start the fadeout of the bubble.

I've tried checking through the code but I can't see any problems.

Answer (score 3):

Your syntax is messed up.  You have `)()` which matches to nothing.  Try this:

```
$(function (){
    $(".message").focus(function() {
        $("#bubble").fadeOut();
    }).blur(function() {
        $("#bubble").fadeIn();
    });
});
```

This will execute the code on document ready.

Comment: Thanks! It was working before so I'm not sure how I managed to change that! This worked :)

Comment: @Francesca, for future reference, you can always use something like http://www.jshint.com to check your syntax, or use JSFiddle's built in syntax checker